# What does $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)$ mean?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was considering the notation we use for integration, and was wondering what it means if we leave various parts out:

- If its $\int_{a}^{b} dx$ it becomes $b-a$, as there is an "invisible" $1$, which we integrate.
- If its $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)$ what does that signify or represent? Can it be evaluated?

Thanks

Comment: Some authors define $\int_a^b f$ to be the integral of $f$ from $a$ to $b$, but I have rarely seen $\int_a^b f(x)$. Did you stumble upon this notation somewhere? Also, in $\int_a^b\,dx$ you indeed have the invisible $1$ there.

Comment: the different integrals have a very defined meaning. Check any book of real analysis about the integral of Riemann, by example. For the integral of Riemann $\mathrm dx$ just indicate the variable respect to what is integrated $f$ in $[a,b]$. The integral of Riemann is defined as a limit of a kind of sums (the sums of Riemann).

Comment: Authors interchangeably use $\int f$ and $\int f(x) dx$, but never $\int f(x)$. Technically, $\int_a^b f(x)$ could be interpreted as $f(x)(b-a)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be interpreted as if the $\mathrm{d}x$ had simply been omitted. It has no other meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing mistake here.

It should be $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$

For other case value of f(x)=1.